# How can i use the local css with easepick

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datepicker

I'm trying to use Easepick with Ionic for building a range `datepicker` but I don't like the idea of using an URL for the CSS.

Is there a way to use the local CSS that easy pick creates when you install it with `npm install`?

```
  const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: dpicker,
    css: [
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/core@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/range-plugin@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
     
    ],
    plugins : [RangePlugin],
    inline: true,
   
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the path to a relative one that refers to the local npm package?

It should look something like:  
`@easepick/core@1.2.1/dist/index.css`
`@easepick/range-plugin@1.2.1/dist/index.css`,